# Count Array Length in JSON Message Object with Amazon Cloudwatch Logs Insights

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Is there any way to get the length of an array found in a JSON object parsed by cloud watch log insights?

For example, when sending a JSON object of the following structure to log insights:

```
{
  names: ['john', 'doe', 'joe', 'schmoe']
}
```

it gets parsed into the following fields:

```
  names.0: john
  names.1: doe
  names.2: joe
  names.3: schmoe
```

and can be accessed by

```
fields @timestamp, names.0, names.1, ...
```

In this example, is there a way to get a `field` called `number_of_names`?

- e.g., `| parse get_length(names) as number_of_names`

Comment: Any idea how to do this?

Comment: i still haven't found a way - resorted to emitting a "count" from my app

Comment: What's worse is this unrolling makes `ispresent(names)` false, and the unrolling _may or may not_ happen.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an ugly workaround for smaller arrays where the max length is known:

```
fields @timestamp, ispresent(names.0) + ispresent(names.1) + ispresent(names.2) + ... + ispresent(names.10) as names_length
```

Comment: unfortunately a valid answer! (cringe)